# SQL concatenate field info in multifield primary key join

Tags: mysql, join

I have two general ledger databases I would like to join together on a multifield primary key.

```
A.FiscalYear + A.Period + A.AcntNo  =   B.FiscalYear + B.Period + B.AcntNo
```

My problem is that in Table `A`, `FiscalYear` is a 4 digit year while in Table `B` it is a 2 digit year.  I'm unable to directly modify the data.

What options do I have to convert the 2 digit year into a 4 digit year so that I can join the tables together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can waive the first 2 digit then you can use `SUBSTRING` function

```
SUBSTRING(A.FiscalYear,2,2) + A.Period + A.AcntNo  =  B.FiscalYear + B.Period + B.AcntNo
```

Comment: concat(substring(d.FiscalYear,2,2),d.period,d.CostCenter+d.Acnt+d.SubAcnt) = concat(b.FiscalYr,b.period,b.AcntNo)

  :::   "'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: @stephenkirsh yes it is. if you are using `+` use: `SUBSTRING(A.FiscalYear,2,2) + A.Period + A.AcntNo  =  B.FiscalYear + B.Period + B.AcntNo`

Comment: I got rid of the concat.  Next it didn't like the fact that the year data is stored as an integer, so I replaced "substring" with "right".

   :::     (right(d.FiscalYear,2)+d.period+d.CostCenter+d.Acnt+d.SubAcnt) = (b.FiscalYr+b.period+b.AcntNo)

Now I'm getting:
The conversion of the carchar value '2070601' overflowed an INT2 column.  Use a larger integer column.

Comment: Ok I tried updating it, but it's not liking the first comma after the substring:   concat((sbustring(d.FiscalYear,2,2),d.period,d.CostCenter,d.Acnt,d.SubAcnt) = concat(b.FiscalYr,b.period,b.AcntNo)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like

```
select
  *
from
  ledger_a a

  inner join ledger_b b on
    b.FiscalYear = a.FiscalYear and
    b.Period = 2000 + a.Period and
    b.AcntNo = a.AcntNo
```

This can be changed to suit your needs. Note that I don't thin indexes would be used when modifying something in the join clause.